# Installing fresh cocoapods does not replace pod binary

Tags: cocoapods

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods
Password:
Fetching: cocoapods-0.25.0.gem (100%)
...
Successfully installed cocoapods-0.25.0
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-0.25.0
1 gem installed
$ pod --version
0.24.0
```

The question is why does it happen?

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Does this problem persist when you start a new shell? Also try removing the old version then installing the new one.

Comment: I tried both variants

Comment: Have you made sure you're using the system ruby by running `which ruby`. If you're actually using another one, updating the system will not effect the currently used ruby in your terminal session.

Comment: $ which ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closed.

It was in /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/pod.

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1385

Answer (score 1):

Apparently your system has 2 sets of Ruby.

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods
```

is not equal to

```
$ gem install cocoapods
```

First one is System Ruby, while second one is user-installed Ruby.

To get the version of cocoapods just installed, use:

```
$ sudo pod --version
```

As an example, in my system, System Ruby has cocoapods version 0.25.00, while User-installed Ruby didn't have cocoapods installed.

Comment: Nope! $ sudo pod --version
Password:
0.24.0